# How to provide object using dependency injection (Hilt) which take as paramater other object?

Tags: android, kotlin, mvvm, dependency-injection, agora.io

I'm new in programming and I'm trying to build my first VideoChat app using MVVM architecture and DI (Hilt) with Agora SDK. I understand that correct way to instantiate **mRtmClient, rtcEngine** objects is to provide it by DI, like we provide Room or Retrofit objects.

But difference from Room and Retrofit is that they need to take object as parameter like in code below **"object: RtmClientListner" and "object: IRtcEngineEventHandler"**:

```
            mRtmClient = RtmClient.createInstance(requireContext(), Constants.APP_ID_TOKEN,
                object : RtmClientListener {
                    override fun onConnectionStateChanged(state: Int, reason: Int) {
                        val text =
                            """Connection state changed to ${state}Reason: $reason """.trimIndent()
                        writeToMessageHistory(text)
                    }
                     ...
```

```
    private val mRtcEventHandler = object : IRtcEngineEventHandler() {
        override fun onJoinChannelSuccess(channel: String?, uid: Int, elapsed: Int) {
            lifecycleScope.launch {
                Toast.makeText(requireContext(), "Joined Channel Successfully", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                    .show()
            }
        }
        ...


    private fun initRtcEngine() {
        try {
            rtcEngine = RtcEngine.create(requireContext(), Constants.APP_ID, mRtcEventHandler)
        } catch (e: Exception) {

        }
    }
```

Till now, I have made my app working, but almost all code for RTM and RTC is in Fragment's including object instantiating, which means my app doesn't survive screen rotations. Also, I think instantiating them in viewmodel isn't correct because context's parameter is needed.

If we provide RtmClientListner and IRtcEngineEventHandler by DI - we need to complete overriding methods. But to give those callbacks some functionality in my app - means to pass functions e.g. writeToMessageHistory(text) function for onConnectionStateChanged callback. And adding additional functions when providing objects by DI doesn't seem correct for me.

So my question are:

1.What is a correct way to provide these Agora object instances in MVVM architecture?

2.Maybe someone can suggest some Android project example where are used some SDK, because examples with Agora SDK in MVVM architecture style I couldn't find.

Thank you in advance.